# Как расширить двумерный массив в python

Tags: python, массивы, pygame, edit

Я делаю игру с бесконечным миром. У меня есть двумерный массив pos_block[x][y]. Каждая ячейка массива соответствует координате в мире. Так как изначально я не могу создать массив нужного размера я хочу его расширять. Как это сделать? Создаю массив с помощью `pos_blocks=[[0 for a in range(-501,501)] for b in range(-801,801)]` и хочу его увеличивать.

Comment: Лучше используйте массивы `Numpy`, там такие вещи делаются довольно элементарно. И в целом доступ к элементам будет быстрее.

Comment: @CrazyElf с numpy уже имел дело, создавая ИИ, но с массивами в них никогда не пытался особо разобраться, кроме как с обычным созданием - изъятием и т.д. А как можно именно в обычном python расширить массив?

Comment: Если ваш список будет постоянно расширяться, то бесконечным мир точно стать не сможет, как минимум закончится память для этого списка :) Думаю, вам скорее надо хранить фиксированного размера список, но который будет меняться в зависимости от положения игрока. Например, всегда хранить 1000 клеток вокруг игрока

Comment: @dIm0n Спасибо за идею!) А как тогда можно сделать так, что при возвращении игрока обратно мир был таким, как раньше? Ведь при перезаписывании массива будут теряться данные об этом.

Comment: @Nezerix хранить как-то отдельно только то, что надо хранить. Если что-то надо сохранять, то в любом случае мир будет конечным

Comment: Это странно, ведь много есть игр с бесконечным сохраняющимся миром, типа известного minecraft или ARK Survival Evolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да так то нет ничего проще, если немного подумать:

```
pos_blocks=[[0 for a in range(-1,1)] for b in range(-2,2)]
print(pos_blocks)

# добавляем ещё один список в конец основного списка
pos_blocks.append([0]*2)
print(pos_blocks)

# добавляем по одному элементу в каждый список внутри основного списка
for l in pos_blocks:
    l.append(0)
print(pos_blocks)
```

Исходный список списков:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

После добавления в него нового списка:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

После добавления элемента в каждый вложенный список:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```